# Cannot read property 'all' of undefined with Restangular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on an application that integrates Rails and AngularJS, and I'm trying to use restangular for all REST functionality, the problem is that when I attempt to post data to create a record I get the error `Can not read property 'all' of undefined at Scope.$scope.addPost`

The angular controller in which I get the error is this.

**poll.controller.js**

```
angular.module('myapp')

.controller('CreatePollCtrl', ['$scope', 'Restangular', function($scope, Restangular) {
  $scope.encuesta = {title: "Encuesta docente"};
  $scope.addPost = function($scope, Restangular) {
    Restangular.all('polls').post($scope.encuesta).then(function() {
    });
  };
}]);
```

And what I try is to send a post request to my Rails controller called **posts_controller.rb**

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_poll, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /polls
  # GET /polls.json
  def index
    @polls = Poll.all
  end

  # GET /polls/1
  # GET /polls/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /polls/new
  def new
    @poll = Poll.new
  end

  # GET /polls/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /polls
  # POST /polls.json
  def create
    @poll = Poll.new(poll_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @poll.save
        format.html { redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Poll was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @poll }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @poll.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /polls/1
  # PATCH/PUT /polls/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @poll.update(poll_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Poll was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @poll }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @poll.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /polls/1
  # DELETE /polls/1.json
  def destroy
    @poll.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to polls_url, notice: 'Poll was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_poll
      @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def poll_params
      params[:poll]
    end
end
```

Just to show you that the routes are correct:

[image: rake routes]

Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: I guess you may miss '/' in front of your url, so try: Restangular.all('/polls')...

Comment: Nope, it wasn't the `/`, it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was totally ok, I just had to remove `$scope` and `Restangular` as argument of the function below `$scope.encuesta` and it worked perfectly D;